# Software reccomendation: diff based restore points

Tags: backup, software-rec, restore, snapshot

i'm looking for software that lets me create multiple restore points that allow me to go back to these points and have my system be in the exact same state as when these restore points were taken.

I would like the restore points to be diff based, so that they don't have to be as big as my entire install.

I would also like it if when i created 2 restore points, and made a change, that the old data is only written to one restore point.  This is unlike lvm, where when you make a change, the old data gets written to each snapshot. So basically only the differences between snapshots should be stored.

I am using fedora 25 with an ext4 file system.

Comment: I ended up just switching to btrfs to get the snapshot functionality, and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be usefult for your case **`rsnapshot`**. From the `manpage` ([rsnapshot manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsnapshot)):

> `rsnapshot` is a filesystem snapshot utility. It can take incremental snapshots of local and remote filesystems for any number of machines.

Concerning your request to use something like `git diff`, `rsnapshot` is able to make an operation that fits your needs. Just use:

> **`rsnapshot diff`**
>   To **check the differences between two directories**, call rsnapshot with the "diff" argument, followed by two backup levels or directory paths.
>
> For example:
>
> `rsnapshot diff daily.0 daily.1`
>   `rsnapshot diff daily.0/localhost/etc daily.1/localhost/etc`
>   `rsnapshot diff /.snapshots/daily.0 /.snapshots/daily.1`
>
> This will call the rsnapshot-diff program, which will scan both directories looking for differences (based on hard links).

There are other alternatives, too; **`actic`** is one of the best (IMHO). Take a look at it at [attic](https://attic-backup.org/)

Comment: I might not understand this properly, but it seems like rsnapshot diff just gives me the differences between 2 snapshots instead of actually making sure only the differences get stored? Or is this not the case?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you question, so. I thought you were looking for a software taking incremental snapshots; I mean, as you requested, taking incremental backups not storing all the pieces in each snapshot. I put `diff` as example to let you understand tha only diffs are saved by the software. Which "point" you want to be restored, is chosen by you.
Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I delete my answer ;)

Comment: No, rsnapshot seems like a good suggestion. I just got a bit confused about diff being seemingly the main function of rsnapshot :p

Comment: It seems that rsnapshot needs 1 original backup to start from, and is diff based from there on out. I'm looking for something that only stores the differences with the current live system.

I'm basically looking for btrfs like features.

Comment: Yep. So I cannot help you finding a software able to keep, starting from the first time, only differences from a *live system* to a *snapshot*. Check other answers. Can I ask you which is exactly your problem taking the first snapshot?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question, but the problem with rsnapshot is that it first needs a full copy of your system (and takes up that amount of space) and then further backups are diff based, relative to the first backup.